# mapping objects from jira rest api

Tags: angular, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to create a custom jira dashboard.

My requirement is to fetch all `issues` from a current sprint and categories into `Open`, `In Progress` & `Closed`.

**To get all sprints of a project - API**

```
https://host.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/PROJECTID?
```

**I used the below API to get all all issues. (Not not anyother better api to fetch )**

```
https://host.com/rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/ACTIVESPRINTID?includeFutureSprints=false&includeHistoricSprints=true&os_username=USERNAME&os_password=PASSWORD
```

Now I wanted to display those details in a `barChart` using `ng2-charts`.

Below is my code.

```
      cardsData = [
      { title: 'X', item: 'x', id: '22407' },
      { title: 'Y', item: 'y', id: '21756' },
    ];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.cardsData.map(x => {
      if (x.id) {
        this.lineChartLabels.push(x.title);
        this.getActiveSprint(x.id);
      }
    });
}

  getActiveSprint(id) {
    this.service.getActiveSprintID(id).subscribe(response => {
      const activeSprintID = response.sprints.slice(-1)[0].id;
      this.getJiraItems(id, activeSprintID);
      this.cardsData.filter((status) => {
        return status.id === id;
      }).map(x => x['activeSprintID'] = activeSprintID);
    });
  }

  getJiraItems(RapidViewID: string, SprintID: string) {
    this.httpSubscription = this.service.getJiraOpenIssues(RapidViewID, SprintID)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        const issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint = response.contents.issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint;
        const completedIssues = response.contents.completedIssues.length;
        const openIssue = [];
        const inProgressIssue = [];
        this.lineData.push(completedIssues);

        issuesNotCompletedInCurrentSprint.filter((item) => {
          if (item.statusId === '1') {
            openIssue.push(item);
          } else if (item.statusId === '3') {
            inProgressIssue.push(item);
          }
        });

        this.totalOpenIssue.push(openIssue.length);
        this.totalInprogressIssue.push(inProgressIssue.length);

        this.pieChartData = [openIssue.length, inProgressIssue.length, completedIssues];

        this.cardsData.filter((status) => {
          return status.title === 'JIRA OVERVIEW';
        }).map(x => x['lineChartData'] = [
          { data: this.totalOpenIssue, label: 'Open' },
          { data: this.totalInprogressIssue, label: 'InProgress' },
          { data: this.lineData, label: 'Completed' }
        ]);

        this.cardsData.filter((status) => {
          return status.id === RapidViewID;
        }).map(x => x['pieChartData'] = this.pieChartData);
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }
```

Issue is, data is not mapping correctly for `open` or `in progress` items also got review comments staying `illegal use of map property`.

Please help me to correct my code and remove unwanted lines.

Comment: please provide minimal verifiable code on stackblitz